# What collection to use in java for storing multiple objects that have the same hashcode?

Tags: java, hashtable

Let's say i want to store records for each class a student attends. Both student and class have unique identifiers, but multiple students can attend same class and a student can attend multiple classes.

I want to arrange those records in such manner that i don't have to search all the records with complexity O(n), but all the objects that have the same class id resolve in the  same slot, much like a hashtable works, except i find that java *HashSet* does not support duplicates.

So my problem is next...i want to return a collection of all those records whose hashcode has resolved to the same location in the table, but that data structure would have to support duplicates ofcourse, because multiple students can attend class x. One such slot would be a list of all records that resolved to the same slot.

Comment: Do you need Students per Class or Classes for a Student? Or both?

Comment: How about a HashMap<Student, Class[]>?

Comment: Being a n-m relationship, I see three classes: Class, Student and Enrollment and I do not see any HashCode conflict.

Comment: Where does the duplicate problem start? I would expect that students, classes and records would all be unique? Note that objects with the same hash code do not have to be equal.

Comment: Did you consider pushing the work off to a database?  If your *n* is so large that a linear search becomes a real problem, using dedicated database management software might be warranted for other reasons too.

Comment: It was not the hash problem...i didn't express myself correctly, i just wanted to have all the attendanceRecords resolve to the same slot in the table, because i believed LinkedHashSet stores such cases that have the identical hash in a list, and just by having the key, i could retrieve the list of all the records in the hash slot. But as i see now, only Map can hold key, value pairs. Keeping a map with Map<ID, Set<Records>> for both student and class is the solution to my problem. Thank you for your  replies. sc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing the general issue of hashcodes first.

Hash tables in general work will still work if you have many distinct keys that map to the same hashcode.  However, hash tables are 1-to-1 maps.  They map each distinct key to one (and only) records / entry.  In the Java context, this applies to all `Map` collections, and to all `Set` collections as well ... modelling a set as a degenerate form of map.

If you want one key to map to (potentially) multiple different records / value, then you need a multi-map data structure.  This can be simulated (using the Java collection types) as a `Map<K, List<V>>` or `Map<K, Set<V>>`.

To summarise:

1. It is the distinctness of the keys that matter, not the distinctness of hashcodes.  (A hash table can deal with hashcode collisions.)
2. If you have non-distinct keys then you need a multi-map.

---

Looking at your particular use-case, what you appear to have is a set of attendance records that have two external keys; i.e. a class id and a source id.  (I'm supposing that each attendance record consists of some data that represents the students attendance at classes.)

The fact that you have two keys here implies that you want to query by both at different places in your application; e.g. "find attendance records for student X",  "find all attendence records for class Y".

This implies that you actually need 2 multi-maps to support those queries; e.g. `Map<StudentID, <Set<AttendanceRecord>>` and `Map<CourseID, <Set<AttendanceRecord>>`.

There are a couple of invariants that you will need to maintain.  The sets must (of course) only contain `AttendanceRecord` objects that pertain to the respective student or course.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what i waas looking for, being able to find all students x who attended y class and all y classes that are attended by student x. Very good, thank you. I didn't know Maps can have collections as parameters too.